# How to create windows context menu with UAC elevation?

Tags: windows, cmd, contextmenu, uac, administrator

I wanted to create a custom context menu for the windows folder where I can run the application with UAC elevation.

What I want, is to create a context menu where I can open the command prompt with administrator privilege. It gets boring every time when I need to run cmd with admin privilege and navigate to the required folder. So, I want to create a context menu for that. I can create the usual context menu, but I couldn't find a way to do it with UAC.

I have researched for a bit and also found a .reg file that does this stuff. I don't want to use the .reg file. I would rather manually do it in regedit.exe and also I don't know much about the .reg file to understand what is going on within the script.

Comment: Maybe post the .reg file?

Comment: @Anders [here is the link to reg file -- codes](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/157437-how-add-create-elevated-shortcut-new-context-menu-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: The actual elevation there is Powershell, nothing special.

Comment: The powershell script appears to use the batch files parent directory as its current directory, ```cd /d "%~dp0"``` and if you wanted to use the passed directory, by way of a menu item, you'd need to change ```PowerShell start """%~0""" -verb RunAs```, which simply runs the batch file again, becuause you'd need it to run the batch file with that previously received argument.